How to get rid of landscape background in smart tv keyboard?
I have a problem with keyboard layout for smart tv (android tv). I want to get rid of white background above the keyboard. How do I do this?
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.customknobkeyboard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/KeyboardTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".KnobKeyboardApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/knob_method" />
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>


I try changing androidmanifest.xml
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUI",

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try this one, should do the trick:
    @Override
    public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
        return false;
    }

This one deactivate full-screen mod, which is default for landscape view.
